# Memory address from string

Tags: c#, memory

I have function to write memory, but I want to import address from string, how to do this?
Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress,
byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

and this:

```
WriteProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0xffffffff, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesWritten);
```

I want to replace this `"0xffffffff"` to `string`, but I don't know how to do this. I try convert string with address to int, but this not working.

Comment: explain more please,"I want to import address from string" ?

Comment: You're trying to parse a number from a string (in a hex format) to an int. The memory address has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Question is not clear. You have the string or you want to format it?

Answer (score 3):

Use something like:

```
string str = "0xffffffffffffffff";
if (str.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    str = str.Substring(2);
}
IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)long.Parse(str, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Note that `long.Parse` doesn't support the `0x`, so if present I remove it.

I'm using the `long.Parse` to support 64bit systems and 32bits systems.

Note that the PInvoke signature you are using is wrong... It will work for 32 bits, but the general one compatible with 32 and 64 bits is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess, 
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress, 
    byte[] lpBuffer, 
    IntPtr dwSize, 
    out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

If you need to manipilate the `IntPtr` you should always convert them to `long`, because a `IntPtr` can be 32 or 64 bits, so a `long` can always contain it.

Comment: I'd avoid the cast to `IntPtr` at the end. It's not wrong, of course, but it's not what the OP is looking for, apparently (he's trying to pass an `int`).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis The `0xffffffff` he is passing is the second parameter of `WriteProcessMemory`, that is the `LPVOID` of the base address to write. So `IntPtr`. His PInvoke is wrong.... I'll write the correct one.